# Bacula - restore with missing tape

Tags: bacula

What's the proper way to perform a restore of available data when one of the tapes is missing (damaged)?

PS. Using Bacula

Answer (score 2):

I would think about using the [bscan](http://www.bacula.org/5.1.x-manuals/en/utility/utility/Volume_Utility_Tools.html#SECTION00270000000000000000) program, which is normally used to recover a damaged database but can also be used to scan the tape for available files.

Answer (score 0):

[bextract](http://www.bacula.org/3.0.x-manuals/en/utility/utility/Volume_Utility_Tools.html#SECTION00260000000000000000) is probably your best bet. It just dumps whatever files are on a tape into a directory of your choice.